# Get elements as flat string from array of jsonb in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a column x with data type jsonb

and the values looks like:

```
[
{"key": "6cd", "type": "text1", "label": "label_text_1", "content": "description"},
{"key": "815", "type": "text2", "label": "label_text_2", "content": "desc2"}
]
```

**How to return an array of strings which contains all the elements with a Postgres query?**

Something like this:

["6cd", "text1","label_text_1","description","815","text2","label_text_2","desc2"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select array_agg(value) from t
join lateral jsonb_array_elements(col) e(v)
on true 
join lateral jsonb_each_text(v)
on true
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jsonb_array_elements(json_column)` to get array elements and `jsonb_each_text(elem)` to get values of all nested objects in these elements:

```
with my_table(id, json_column) as (
values(
    1, 
    '[
        {"key": "6cd", "type": "text1", "label": "label_text_1", "content": "description"},
        {"key": "815", "type": "text2", "label": "label_text_2", "content": "desc2"}
    ]'::jsonb)
)

select id, array_agg(val)
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_column) as a(elem)
cross join jsonb_each_text(elem) as e(key, val)
group by id

 id |                             array_agg                             
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {6cd,text1,label_text_1,description,815,text2,label_text_2,desc2}
(1 row)
```

Comment: what do you think in the matter of performance if i have a lot of json_column in a big join query between tables which i want to apply your idea to?

Comment: It's hard to say because *a lot of* and *big* are relative concepts. In general, you should avoid dynamic decomposing json documents as it is always costly. You should rather [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables if they are going to be large.